# Read Named Range Names into VBA array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out how I can get the names of ranges in a given worksheet into an array. I've got as far as the listnames function but that seems to list them all in one go. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
Sub listum()
    Dim ary(1 To 3) As String
    With ActiveWorkbook
        If .Names.Count > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To .Names.Count
                MsgBox (i & "  " & .Names(i).Name & "  " & Range(.Names(i)).Address)
                ary(i) = .Names(i).Name
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

will display them and put them into an array.

Size the array to suit your needs.
Insure that there are no *non-Range* Names in the workbook.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll give this a go

Comment: Have just tried this, I din't know about "names" - but it's taking the workbook name, print area etc into the array, which is causing problems down the line. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JamesMcS  You need to test for them......after all, `PrintArea` is a valid group of cells, just like any other user-defined Named Range !

Comment: @JamesMcS: Did you find any way to exclude them well? I am building a small template exporter for word using Named Ranges and it would be good to exclude built-in fields https://github.com/coezbek/office-automation-excel2word-document-properties

Answer (score 0):

My version is I used dynamic array:

```
    Sub TestNamedRange()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim intCount As Long
    Dim NameArray() As String
    'count number of named ranges
    intCount = ThisWorkbook.Names.Count
    ReDim NameArray(intCount)  'for dynamic number of named ranges
    'assign all names to each array element
    For i = 1 To intCount
      NameArray(i) = ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name 'remove .Name if you want address range only
    Next
   'check array elements
   For Each ele In NameArray
     Debug.Print ele
   Next
  'manipulate your array here
  End Sub
```

Comment: Though rare I have seen workbooks with more than 32767 names so best to use a Long rather than an integer. Since use of an Integer do not offer any advantage over Long I'd advise to always use Long to avoid problems like this.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll give this a go

Comment: @JamesMcS please give it an up.  I am just starting :-) thank you.